# Is a ray actually a half-line?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

I just started studying elementary geometry with Kiselev's plane geometry book. In §5 of the introduction, the author talks about rays, calling them 'half-lines'. That got me wondering whether an arbitrary ray, say $(E, +\infty)$ (this might not be good notation; I apologize, I'm new to this) is s.t. the distance from $E$ to $+\infty$ is in some sense equal to the distance from $E$ to $-\infty$. This might help:

$$-\infty\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots\cdots E ------+\infty$$

I suspect that either (i) that makes no sense, (ii) the distances are obviously equal, or (iii) the distances might be equal, but there's no way to tell, or (iv) there's some other option. Whichever is the case, any explanation/guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two sets have the same cardinality, because there exists a bijective function between them:
$$f \colon (E,+\infty) \to (-\infty,E), \quad x \mapsto 2E - x.$$
In this sense, there are equally (however uncountably) many elements in both sets.
Distance is another topic. The distances from $E$ to $+\infty$ and from $E$ to $-\infty$ are of course both infinite.
Note that $f$ is also an isometry (i.e., a distance-preserving function), because for any two points $x,y \in (E,+\infty)$ it holds that $d(f(x),f(y)) = d(2E-x,2E-y) = d(x,y)$.

Comment: Aha! Thank you, this is great.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to somehow compare these infinite distances? Are there larger and smaller infinite distances? Do you think it's possible to somehow compare these infinite distances? Are there larger and smaller infinite distances? For example, would it be fair to say that the infinite distance from E to +infinity formed by natural numbers is somehow shorter than the infinite distance from E to +infinity formed by real or rational numbers?

Comment: For any distance $R$, there is a point $E+R$ in one and $E-R$ in the other direction. "Different distances" would mean that this is not possible for some big $R$.

Answer (score 7):

A half-line is just a set of the form $a + tb$ for $t \ge 0$, in a vector space over the reals. In the plane this just amounts to lines that are "cut off", i.e. have an endpoint, but then extend towards infinity. Say $\{(x,0): x \ge 0\}$, the positive x-axis, or the negative one too, is an example. (in the former case we have $a = (0,0), b = (1,0)$, say.) A full line is of the form $a + tb$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$, so it extends towards infinity in two directions, not just one.

Comment: Let's consider (0,0). Is the distance from that point in the +x direction equal to the distance in the -x direction? I'd understand if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I fear that it doesn't even make sense to talk about a 'distance', when one of the 'points' is not really a point, but something that can only be approached.

Comment: Yes, you should not take the $\infty$ to be some point. Just work with a definition, and the idea that it's a line that just goes in one direction, instead of two. If you leave out the endpoint, so take $t>0$ instead of $t\ge 0$, you get what's sometimes called an "open ray".